# Extract differences between two XML files that contains directory structures, using linQ?

Tags: linq-to-xml, xmldiff

i'm implementing a client-server program that synchronize files between computers.
At some point, when the client connects to the server, an XML file that contains the directory structure of the location that must be synchronized with the server  is sent to the server.
If it is not the first time when the client connects, on the server exists such a XML files  so there must be found the differences between those 2 files and request from client only the ones that files that have been changed or new.
My problem is... how can I find those differences between the XML's.
I have  2 XML samples(one XML can have and 1Gb).

**First XML (source.xml)**:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<RootDirectory name="New folder" dateCreated="5/20/2013 7:16:32 PM">
  <Folder  name="New folder1" >
    <File name="New Text Document11.txt" />
    <File name="New Text Document12.txt"  />
  </Folder>
   <File name="New Text Document1.txt"  />
</RootDirectory>
```

**Second XML (changed.xml)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootDirectory name="New folder" dateCreated="5/20/2013 7:15:50 PM">
   <Folder name="New folder1">
      <File name="New Text Document11.txt" />
      <File name="New Text Document12.txt" />
   </Folder>
   <Folder name="New folder2">
      <Folder name="New folder21">
         <File name="New Text Document211.txt" />
         <Folder name="New folder211">
            <File name="New Text Document2111.txt" />
            <Folder name="New folder2111">
               <File name="New Text Document21111.txt" />
            </Folder>
         </Folder>
      </Folder>
      <File name="New Text Document21.txt" />
   </Folder>
   <File name="New Text Document1.txt" />
</RootDirectory>
```

I found an example  that uses LinQ to XML http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45233/Diff-in-XML-files-with-LINQ, but the XML structure used there is different, and it does not help me very much.
Given the fact that i can have the tag `Folder` and `File` nested inside other nodes..i really don't know how to find the differences ...

Can someone give me an idea?

Thank you!

Best Regards, 
Oana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be an algorithm like this:

- extract all folders from old file
- extract all folders from new file
- fetch new folders with [List Except method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) => new = list2.Except(list1)
- fetch same folders with [List Intersect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910215%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) => possibleChanges =  list2.Intersect(list1)
- compare content for changed lists
- repeat all of this (recursion or iteration) for all levels

Example code:

```
var xml1 = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<RootDirectory name=""New folder"" dateCreated=""5/20/2013 7:16:32 PM"">
  <Folder  name=""New folder1"" >
    <File name=""New Text Document11.txt"" />
    <File name=""New Text Document12.txt""  />
  </Folder>
   <File name=""New Text Document1.txt""  />
</RootDirectory>";

var xml2 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<RootDirectory name=""New folder"" dateCreated=""5/20/2013 7:15:50 PM"">
   <Folder name=""New folder1"">
      <File name=""New Text Document11.txt"" />
      <File name=""New Text Document12.txt"" />
      <File name=""New Text Document13.txt"" />
   </Folder>
   <Folder name=""New folder2"">
      <Folder name=""New folder21"">
         <File name=""New Text Document211.txt"" />
         <Folder name=""New folder211"">
            <File name=""New Text Document2111.txt"" />
            <Folder name=""New folder2111"">
               <File name=""New Text Document21111.txt"" />
            </Folder>
         </Folder>
      </Folder>
      <File name=""New Text Document21.txt"" />
   </Folder>
   <File name=""New Text Document1.txt"" />
</RootDirectory>";

var xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1);
var xmlDoc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2);

var f1 = allFolders(xmlDoc1.Root);
var f2 = allFolders(xmlDoc2.Root);
var newFolders = f2.Except(f1);
var sameFolders = f2.Intersect(f1);
// completely new folders, content is new => no further checks needed!
newFolders.Dump();
// check if content of same folders has changed
foreach (var sameFolder in sameFolders)
{
    var oldContent = folderContent(xmlDoc1.Root.Descendants("Folder").Where (r => r.Attribute("name").Value == sameFolder).ToList());
    var newContent = folderContent(xmlDoc2.Root.Descendants("Folder").Where (r => r.Attribute("name").Value == sameFolder).ToList());
    var newFiles = newContent.Except(oldContent);
}

private List<string> folderContent(IEnumerable<XElement> nodes)
{
    var files = new List<String>();
    nodes.ToList().ForEach(n => files.AddRange(n.Elements("File").Select (x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList()));
    return files;
}

private List<string> allFolders(XElement node)
{
    var folders = node.Descendants("Folder").ToList().Select (e => e.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
    return folders;
}
```

Output:

```
//changed folders
New folder2
New folder21
New folder211
New folder2111

// new files for New folder 1
NewTextDocument13.txt
```

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for answering my question. I have one more question. My Xml files can have and more than 1Gb. Could i use the solution you provided me? Thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: If you are on a 32bit system, then files up to 2GB should be fine. If you are on a 64bit system LINQ2XML should be able to handle even files larger than 2GB ([more info here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/a386a0b2-b8c1-47b3-9422-d02cf214409f/)). If the approach using LINQ2XML is to slow, then you could try implementing the algorithm using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) instead.